# bluetooth socket not receiving packet

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, bluetooth

I am working on a bluetooth socket for past 10 days. I have to switch between client and server mode. I have written a piece of code. I was able to send the packet fine but when i was working for listening mode I faced two problems.
1.The accept was in block mode so it was not able to go back to send mode.
2. I made the socket non block using FNCTL()

But now issue is coming that is is switching between two modes perfectly but it is not receiving any packet. My code is as follow:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <bluetooth/l2cap.h>
#define MAXPROFILES  2


int SetTimer(struct timeval *tv, time_t sec)
{
    gettimeofday(tv,NULL);
    tv->tv_sec+=sec;
    return 1;
}

void start_scan()
{   
    struct sockaddr_l2 addr1 = { 0 };
    int s=0,h, status,f,contacted;
    int search=1;
    char *message = "hello!";
    char dest[18] = "01:23:45:67:89:AB";
    struct neighbor
    {
    char peer[19];
    }   p[h];

    unsigned char buf[1024];
    inquiry_info *devices = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, sock, len, flags,cmp;
    int x=0,i;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };


    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
    if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) 
    {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }


    len  = 3;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    devices = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));
    struct timeval tv;
    SetTimer(&tv,15);
    while(search == 1)
    {   //fprintf(stderr,"\t%d \n", time);
        num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &devices, flags);
        fprintf(stderr,"%s (%d) %d\n", "done scanning, found ", j, num_rsp);
        if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

        for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++)
        {
        ba2str(&(devices+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        fprintf(stderr,"\t%s \n", addr);
        cmp= strncmp(addr,"10:2E:AF:EB:33:BD",8);
        if(cmp==0)
        {
         fprintf(stderr,"\t%s \t%d\n", addr,cmp);
            for(f=0;f<=h;f++)
            {
                if(p[f].peer[18]==addr[19])
                contacted=1;
            }
                if(contacted==1)
                {
                contacted=0;
                continue;
                }

            s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_L2CAP);

            // set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
            addr1.l2_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
            addr1.l2_psm = htobs(0x1001);
            strncpy(dest, addr, 18);

            str2ba( dest, &addr1.l2_bdaddr );

// connect to server
            status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr1, sizeof(addr1));

// send a message
            if( status == 0 )
            {

            status = write(s, "hello", 10);
            h++;
            p[h].peer[18]=addr[19];

            }

            if( status < 0 )
            {
            perror("uh oh");
            }
        }
      }  // for
     x++;
     if(!(x%2))
        flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
     else
        flags = 0x00;
    if (CheckTimer(&tv,5)==1)
        {   //close(sock);
            fprintf(stderr,"listen....\n");



        start_listen(s);
        }
    }
}
    int start_listen(int s)     
    { struct sockaddr_l2 addr1 = { 0 },rem_addr = { 0 };;
     fd_set fds;
    int client, bytes_read,sock_flags;
    char buf1[1024] = {0};
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
    struct timeval tv;


    addr1.l2_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    addr1.l2_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    addr1.l2_psm = htobs(0x1001);
    sock_flags=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
    fcntl(s,F_SETFL,sock_flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr1, sizeof(addr1));
    SetTimer(&tv,15);
    // put socket into listening mode
    while(!0)
        {
                listen(s, 1);
                //fprintf(stderr,"I am listening....\n");


    // accept one connection
                client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
                //fprintf(stderr,"I failed....\n");
                FD_ZERO(&fds);
                FD_SET(s,&fds);             
                ba2str( &rem_addr.l2_bdaddr, buf1 );

                memset(buf1, 0, sizeof(buf1));

    // read data from the client
                bytes_read = read(client, buf1, sizeof(buf1));
                    if( bytes_read > 0 ){
                        printf("received [%s]\n", buf1);
                    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf1);
                    }
                close(client);

                    if (CheckTimer(&tv,5)==1)
                        {fprintf(stderr,"done listening...");

                        SetTimer(&tv,15);
                        return 1;
                        }
            }//while of the listening mode

} 


int CheckTimer(struct timeval *tv, time_t sec)
{
    struct timeval ctv;
    gettimeofday(&ctv,NULL);
    if((ctv.tv_sec > tv->tv_sec))
    {   
        gettimeofday(tv,NULL);
        tv->tv_sec+=sec;
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{start_scan();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by entering the following command again in listen mode before binding.

```
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_L2CAP);
```

But now the issue is my `close(client)` is not working. I am not able to close the client and listen to new client. Do anyone know why?

Comment: You should add your new issue as a new question, with this answer to your problem flagged as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need at all to open the server socket! (*Unless* your remote device is doing something *very* odd!!)  A socket can be used for send ***and*** receive -- regardless of whether it is a client socket or a server socket.

Remove all the code to do the listen+accept etc, and write and read to the original (client) socket.(The one done with: "`connect(s,`...")

If your remote device *really* needs the two different connections. The use a new variable to hold the socket handle and don't have the server socket handle overwrite the original client handle.